# XMPP MUC Occupant kickout

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, openfire, strophe

I am trying to connect to a chat room using xmpp, strophe, and javascript.
I was able to join a chat room using:

```
connection.muc.join(room_name + "@conference.louis-tosh/" + nickname);
```

The occupant joins the room successfully; however, he/she gets automatically kicked out of the room after a certain period.
I have been trying to solve the issue for the past few days.

Is this an openfire configuration error?
I need to fix this error and make the occupant permanently member of the chat room until he/she decide to leave the room.

Comment: What's the log traffic say prior to to and when the disconnect happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by adding a nickname of the logged in user.
The user was being kicked out due to overlapping nicknames in the room.

The solution was as such:

```
connection.connect(login_jid + '/anyNickname', password, onConnect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get a presence error (type='error') with a conflict element. You can then prompt the user to select a new/different one.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can achieve this goal from openfire settings, here i am attaching a screen capture for helping you